# where I put script tag so that it parse after the document is fully loaded?

Tags: javascript, html

I don't want to add eventListener `DOMContentloaded` for a moment I just want to is there a way to make a script tag executed after this following `div` tag

```
<html>
 <head>


  </head>

   <body>
        <div id="name">12 </div>
        <script>
                  var name =  document.getElementById("name");
                  name.innerHTML = "13"; 
        </script
   </body>
```

Also want to know why the script tag is executed before the DOM gets loaded

Comment: Are you saying that the `div` isn't available when your script runs? What you're currently doing should work.

Comment: @Marc B I want to know why the script tag is executed first? The marked question didn't answer my question.

Comment: @squint yes ...Because it is always recommended to put the script tag just before the closing of body tag... So why this is not working

Comment: Try changing the variable name from `name` to something else, like `x`. There's a default global variable called `name` that gets in the way of your assignment because it converts it to a string.

Comment: thnks it is working now!

Comment: Glad to hear that. In general, it's not a bad idea to wrap your code in a function so that your variables aren't global.